# Why does the signal generator voltage change in this circuit?

Tags: circuit-design, bjt, oscilloscope, jfet

[image]

In this circuit, when I measure with an oscilloscope the square wave I get this:
(The switch S is open in both measurements)

[image]

But when I change the R2 resistor to 15 Ohm, I get this:

[image]

Why does that happen?

Comment: Your input voltage is too small to turn the FET on and off?

Comment: are you asking?

Comment: what are you measuring?

Comment: I'm measuring Vi, the square wave source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A J-FET junction is like a diode when the junction is forwards biased. that will reduce the amplitude of your signal generator output.

Comment: Just one question, in the first situation the voltage amplitude isn't reduced, that means that the GS junction isn't forward biased right?